# Oracle SQL compare values from 2 tables and set yes/no

Tags: sql, oracle

These are my example tables:

| Table 1 | table 2 column1 | Table2 column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CONCAT1 | Concat2 | Valid |
| A12 | A11 |  |
| A12 | A12 |  |
| B12 |  |  |
| A12 |  |  |

i would like to add a Yes or No in the Valid column in table 2 , if A11 and A12 from concat 2 table 2 cand be found in Concat1 table1.

It's probably simple, but i can't figure it out at all.

Expected:

| Table 1 | table 2 column1 | Table2 column2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| CONCAT1 | Concat2 | Valid |
| A12 | A11 | No |
| A12 | A12 | Yes |
| B12 |  |  |
| A12 |  |  |

Thanks !!!

Comment: Could you please add the table structure /sample data and expected result in a tabular format. The line in your question is little confusing

Comment: Yea, i realized, i was trying to fix it now :)

Comment: How do you join those two tables? Is it a cross join? or Are there any other columns present?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `EXISTS` and a correlated sub-query:

```sql
SELECT concat2,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.concat1 = t2.concat2)
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS valid
FROM   table2 t2
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE Table1 (CONCAT1) AS
SELECT 'A12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'B12' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12' FROM DUAL;

CREATE TABLE table2 (concat2, valid) AS
SELECT 'A11', CAST(NULL AS VARCHAR2(3)) FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT 'A12', NULL FROM DUAL
```

Outputs:

> | CONCAT2 | VALID |
> | --- | --- |
> | A11 | No |
> | A12 | Yes |

---

Or, if you want to update the table then:

```sql
UPDATE table2 t2
SET valid = CASE
            WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.concat1 = t2.concat2)
            THEN 'Yes'
            ELSE 'No'
            END
WHERE valid IS NULL;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=11d4ff5ed149966b3bd929b6d1e2cdf6)*

Comment: Query works perfect. So now if i want to write the Yes/No in the actual table i can do something like this:

Update table2 a
Set a.valid=
(SELECT concat2,
       CASE
       WHEN EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM table1 t1 WHERE t1.concat1 = t2.concat2)
       THEN 'Yes'
       ELSE 'No'
       END AS valid
FROM   table2 t2)
Where valid is null;

Comment: @LazyAlex I've updated the answer to include that.